# How to return express api response in a structured manner

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i need help on this my express API endpoint. I need to get the users details response in a customise structured manner like

```
{
 "userId": "a38a8320-b750-41d1-a2d3-117dd286eeb5", //guid
 "firstName": "John", //string
 "lastName": "Doe",//string
 "accountId": "47cabec9-4e05-4744-b1c3-602a51dd86bc"//guid
}
```

My get endpoint is

```
router.get("/users", async (req, res) => {
  const users = await User.find();
  res.send(users)
});
```

The result I'm getting from postman below

```
[
    {
        "_id": "ba3136dd-94e8-48e6-89aa-1457c8bc540a",
        "firstName": "Segun",
        "lastName": "Ajibaye",
        "accountId": "8f061737-9500-4760-909d-9591c6c6c340",
        "__v": 0
    }
    
]
```

Comment: What should happen if `User.find()` returns multiple users? Or no user? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to achieve that.

The callback you pass to the map method will be executed on every item inside the users array, and it will generate a new array with the result of each operation.

So your code could be like this:

```
router.get("/users", async (req, res) => {
  const users = await User.find();
  const mappedUsers = users.map(function (user) {
   return {
    userId: user._id,
    firstName: user.firstName,
    lastName: user.lastName,
    accountId: user.accountId
   }
  })
  res.send(mappedUsers)
});
```